My power ON/OFF PCB circuit does not work as expected
I've designed a PCB that includes a power ON/OFF logic circuit, allowing a linear regulator to be turned on and off with a button. Here’s how it’s supposed to work:

This circuit provides ON/OFF control for a 3.3V power supply using
a push button and a D flip-flop.
Power Switching and Regulation: The MOSFET (Q1) switches between USB (VBUS) and battery (VBAT) power, feeding into the linear regulator (U4) to produce a stable 3.3V output.
Button Debouncing: When the push button (PWR_BUT) is pressed, its signal passes through two Schmitt triggers (NC7WZ14P6X) to remove any noise and bounce. This provides a clean signal to the D flip-flop's clock input.
ON/OFF Toggle Logic: The D flip-flop (DFLIP)(SN74LVC1G80DCKR) toggles its output (Q) each time it receives a clock pulse from the button. When Q is high, it enables ON_OFF_3V3, turning the power on. When Q is low, it disables ON_OFF_3V3, turning the power off.
The Schmitt triggers are essential to stabilize the button signal since the D flip-flop lacks internal hysteresis.

The flip flop (DFLIP) needs a high speed input clock signal to work.

So with VBUS supplying 5V, the maximum clock transition time is 5ns*5=25ns. That is why I choose the inverter (SCA/SCB/SCC, they are same component) with schmitt trigger
NC7WZ14P6X, its "Ultra-High Speed: tPD 3.2ns (Typical) into 50pF at 5V Vcc".
But the circuit does not work as expected. So I took an oscilloscope and looked at the signals.
We begin with the signal coming into the schmitt trigger (SCA/SCB/SCC).

It takes about 4.6us to reach high state. But that is completely fine since we have schmitt trigger.
The output from the inverter (after two inversions) takes 430ns to go to high, which is far worse then the 3.2ns advertised.

This makes the D flip flop (DFLIP) have a very unexpected behavior, sometimes it flips and sometimes it does not. And sometimes flips multiple times, and hence the circuit does not work. Can anyone explain the behavior I am seeing, or if you maybe see a solution or improvment.
Component values:
R6: 68k
C10: 1u
R9: 3.3k
C10: 1u
R10: 100K

It appears to work exactly as the circuit is drawn. Schmitt triggers will appear to delay a pulse when the input pulse has a very slow rise time. In addition add component values to your schematic and please refer to component IDs when talking about them in the text of your question.

@Andyaka Yes, but the schmitt trigger inverter (SCA/SCB/SCC) does not have the timings as the inverter should. And that causes the whole circuit to loose its function.

If you are unable to edit the schematic to show the values alongside each component is this because it's not your self-generated schematic?

@Andyaka It very much is my schematic but right now I don't have access to the license so I can only have it it viewing mode. That is why I cannot show values alongside each component right now. I added the values to the bottom of my post.

You can use paint.exe (or similar) to add values to the drawing. I don't know anybody who likes a circuit that doesn't directly contain component values.

Is your scope BW set to full, and are your scope probes suitable for measuring a risetime of a couple of ns?  You can be pretty confident that the logic gates will have the specified risetime under the specified conditions in the datasheet, so if you're not getting that, it's either that your measurement, or your conditions (loading, etc.) are significantly different from the datasheet. I suppose there's a very small chance that you have counterfeit parts, or parts that have been (ESD?) damaged in the exact way to damage the pull-up device, but highly unlikely.
